# Proof of a conditional joint entropy inequality

Tags: inequality, random-variables, entropy

Suppose $K\in\mathbb{N}$ and the sets $\mathcal{S}\subseteq\{1,\dots,K\}$ and $\mathcal{S}^c=\{1,\dots,K\}\setminus\mathcal{S}$. Finally, let's use the notation for sets of random variable as $X_\mathcal{S}=\{X_i:i\in \mathcal{S}\}$ and $Y_{\mathcal{S}^c}=\{Y_i:i\in \mathcal{S}^c\}$. I am trying to lower bound the entropy $H(X_\mathcal{S}|Y_{\mathcal{S}^c})$ as:
\begin{equation}
H(X_\mathcal{S}|Y_{\mathcal{S}^c})\geq\frac{1}{|\mathcal{S}|-1}\sum\limits_{k\in\mathcal{S}}H(X_\mathcal{S}|X_k,Y_{\mathcal{S}^c})\label{a}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
So, I can show the following steps:
\begin{eqnarray}
H(X_\mathcal{S}|Y_{\mathcal{S}^c})&=&\frac{1}{|\mathcal{S}|}\sum\limits_{k\in\mathcal{S}}H(X_\mathcal{S},X_k|Y_{\mathcal{S}^c})\\
&=&\frac{1}{|\mathcal{S}|}\sum\limits_{k\in\mathcal{S}}\Big\{H(X_\mathcal{S}|X_k,Y_{\mathcal{S}^c})+H(X_k|Y_{\mathcal{S}^c})\Big\}\\
&\geq&\frac{1}{|\mathcal{S}|}\sum\limits_{k\in\mathcal{S}}\Big\{H(X_\mathcal{S}|X_k,Y_{\mathcal{S}^c})\Big\}+\frac{1}{|\mathcal{S}|}H(X_\mathcal{S}|Y_{\mathcal{S}^c})
\end{eqnarray}
by using the generalizations of the properties
\begin{equation}
H(X,Y|Z)=H(X|Z)+H(Y|X,Z)
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
H(X,Y)\leq H(X)+H(Y)
\end{equation}
but I cannot proceed to the next step to see that eq. (\ref{a}) holds.

**EDIT**

Initially, I forgot to mention the restriction of $|\mathcal{S}|>1$

Comment: Is (1) a valid (known) bound or a conjecture of yours that you hope to prove? The bound expression appears to not be applicable for the case $|\mathcal{S}|=1$, although no such restriction is stated in the problem description.

Comment: @Stelios It is a valid bound at least according to its author and I am trying to prove it. You are right about $|\mathcal{S}|>1$ (I have edited this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got the right answer. Just shuffle around some terms:

\begin{align}
H(X_\mathcal{S}|Y_{\mathcal{S}^c})&\geq\frac{1}{|\mathcal{S}|}\sum\limits_{k\in\mathcal{S}}\Big\{H(X_\mathcal{S}|X_k,Y_{\mathcal{S}^c})\Big\}+\frac{1}{|\mathcal{S}|}H(X_\mathcal{S}|Y_{\mathcal{S}^c}) \\
&\Updownarrow \\
\left(1 - \frac{1}{|\mathcal{S}|}\right)H(X_\mathcal{S}|Y_{\mathcal{S}^c}) &\geq \frac{1}{|\mathcal{S}|}\sum\limits_{k\in\mathcal{S}}\Big\{H(X_\mathcal{S}|X_k,Y_{\mathcal{S}^c})\Big\} \\
&\Updownarrow \\
H(X_\mathcal{S}|Y_{\mathcal{S}^c})&\geq\frac{1}{|\mathcal{S}|-1}\sum\limits_{k\in\mathcal{S}}H(X_\mathcal{S}|X_k,Y_{\mathcal{S}^c})
\end{align}